# How To: Project Organization and Output

Tags: c#, ide, namespaces

I have a fairly well project that I am developing right now, but I need to separate some of the components based on their intended run-time "environments."

For example:

MyNameSpace.MyProductName.Admin (parent class - helper classes)
MyNameSpace.MyProductName.Admin.Terminal (child class - UI for End User: consumer)
MyNameSpace.MyProductName.Admin.Database (child class - UI for DB Admin and monitoring)
MyNameSpace.MyProductName.Admin.Management (child class - UI for End User: administration)

Is there a way to separate these logically in the IDE where the output will produce the following structure?

MyNameSpace\MyProductName\Admin\MyProductName.*.dlls

MyNameSpace\MyProductName\Admin\Terminal\MyProductName.*.dlls, MyProductName.Terminal.exe

MyNameSpace\MyProductName\Admin\Database\MyProductName.*.dlls, MyProductName.Database.exe

MyNameSpace\MyProductName\Admin\Management\MyProductName.*.dlls, MyProductName.Management.exe

Or will I need to create separate projects for each UI?

Thanks In Advance,

E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, a project can produce only 1 o/p, so you need to organize these as projects in a solution and add the project with the exe as the startup project for debugging.

Comment: Ah, I guess I should have mentioned that these these are already projects in a solution.

So, I should have asked if it is possible to have projects in projects.

;-)

But, I guess that kinda answers my question.  Will create more projects under solution :-)

Comment: VS does provide a mechanism for creating nested projects. Take a look at 'FlavoredProjectBase' to get an idea. It is a lot of work unless you intend to focus on extending the project structure as your work itself.

Comment: @FlavoredProjectBase

Thank you for the info MohitC.

I am currently using SharpDevelop for this project, but I intend to request VS2008 as part of my compensation for developing this project during my personal time for my employer.

Kind of an "if you think you can do it, then show me" situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add another solution folder under the "MyNameSpace" solution folder.

This allowed me to separate the UI items from the application items.

Thanks Again!